# Exclude setting on integer field in term query

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents contain an integer array field, storing the id of tags describing them. Given a specific tag id, I want to extract a list of top tags that occur most frequently together with the provided one.

I can solve this problem associating a *term aggregation* over the tag id field to a *term filter* over the same field, but the list I get back obviously always starts with the album id I provide: all documents matching my filter have that tag, and it is thus the first in the list.

I though of [using the `exclude` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values) to avoid creating the problematic bucket, but as I'm dealing with an integer field, that seems not to be possible: this query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "tag_ids": "00001"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 3,
        "field": "tag_ids",
        "exclude": "00001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns an error saying that `Aggregation [tags] cannot support the include/exclude settings as it can only be applied to string values`.

Is it possible to avoid getting back this bucket?

Comment: I had the same problem and came up with 2 possible solutions *1* index the Id as string *2* add a duplicate field Id_string as string. Went with second option. Obviously not the best approach but does the job. I was wondering is there a better way to use "include" "exclude" terms with non string values. maybe converting them to string with Script ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, as of Elasticsearch 1.4, a shortcoming of ES itself.

After the [community proposed](http://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/7714) this change, [the functionality has been added](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/7727) and will be included in Elasticsearch 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be fixed since version 1.5.0. 
Look at this: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/7727

Comment: yep, starting the discussion about it was definitely a good idea 
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/7714

Answer (score 0):

While it is enroute to being fixed: My workaround is to have the aggregation use a script instead of direct access to the field, and let that script use the value as string.
Works well and without measurable performance loss.